# Partition by / over

Tags: t-sql

Identification of the occurence of 'a' in the team field per member and date occurences (as a group) is required. A data sample is as following:

```
**member & date**|                    **Team**
a010112|                                  a
a010112|                                  b   
a010112|                                  c  
a010112|                                  d
b010112|                                  b
b010112|                                  b
c010112|                                  a
c010112|                                  b
c010112|                                  c
```

The outcome desired is as follows:

```
**member & date|                   **team**|       **Occurrence of 'a' per member & date**
a010112|                                  a|             yes
a010112|                                  b|             yes
a010112|                                  c|             yes
a010112|                                  d|             yes
b010112|                                  b|             no
b010112|                                  b|             no
c010112|                                  a|             yes
c010112|                                  b|             yes
c010112|                                  c|             yes
```

The calculated field - Occurrence of 'a' per member & date grouping is to be a calculated field from a datawarehouse query via a case statement / partition by  / over.  Could some assistance be provided for required syntax?

Thank You,

Comment: case when team  = 'a' then 'yes' over(partition by member & date) else 'no' end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Declare @t Table ([Member and Date] Varchar(50), Team Varchar(10))
Insert Into @t Values
    ('a010112','a'),('a010112','b'),('a010112','c'),('a010112','d'),
    ('b010112','b'),('b010112','b'),
    ('c010112','a'),('c010112','b'),('c010112','c')

SELECT
    x.[Member and Date]
    ,x.[Team]   
    ,[Occurrence of 'a' per member & date] = CASE WHEN y.[Member and Date] IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END

From @t x
Left Join(Select Distinct [Member and Date]
     From @t Where Team = 'a')y
On x.[Member and Date] = y.[Member and Date]
```

[image]